# How to not allow a circular UIView to recognize touches outside of it's circular bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have two views stacked on-top of each other. Let's say view B is stacked on-top of a larger view A. View B is circular and should not accept touches outside of circle instead the larger view A should accept the touches.

I've tried overriding the touchesBegan method of a custom PanGesture recognizer of view B to check if it's with-in the circular path and then call touches cancelled on the recognizers super like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    let isInPath = self.path.containsPoint(location)

    if(isInPath){
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        self.rotation = rotationForLocation(location)
    }else{
        // touch started outside of path so cancel touch
        super.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

It prevents view B from accepting the touches outside of the circular path, but view A does not accept the touches. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Override the hitTest method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can add two gesture recognizers, one of which will specify a delegate with a `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` method that will only start the gesture if it was within the circle. You can then have the non-circular gesture succeed only if the circular one fails.

```
// add square view

let subview = UIView(frame: frame)
subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
subview.userInteractionEnabled = true
view.addSubview(subview)

// add circular shapelayer (so I can see the circle)

let circularShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circularShapeLayer.frame = subview.bounds
circularShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: subview.bounds).CGPath
circularShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
subview.layer.addSublayer(circularShapeLayer)

// add gesture that will use delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` to determine if you started in the circle

let circlePanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleCircularPan:")
circlePanGesture.delegate = self
subview.addGestureRecognizer(circlePanGesture)

// add a gesture recognizer that will only be recognized if the prior gesture recognizer fails

let squarePanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSquarePan:")
squarePanGesture.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(circlePanGesture)
subview.addGestureRecognizer(squarePanGesture)
```

The delegate method might look like:

```
func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let center = CGPoint(x: gesture.view!.bounds.size.width / 2.0, y: gesture.view!.bounds.size.height / 2.0)
    let location = gesture.locationInView(gesture.view)
    let distance = hypot(center.x - location.x, center.y - location.y)
    return distance < (gesture.view!.bounds.size.width / 2.0)
}
```

Note, I'm adding both of these gestures to the same subview (because if I have overlapping views, both of which have `userInteractionEnabled`, only the top one if getting the gestures).

Answer (score 0):

Do not cancel the touches, forward them to the A object instead.

Comment: Do you mean forward to view A? If so I should let you know that this gesture recognizer is inside of custom UIControl and View A and view B are two separate instances of this custom UIControl. Is it advisable to pass this info between two separate UIControls?

Comment: Sorry I meant A and I changed my answer to reflect it. If both are handled in one object, then there's no problem. You might want to define two paths then and check for the "B" one else if "A" one format. Right now, when it is not in "B" nothing happens..